# Internal problem using Google Earth Engine function

Tags: google-earth-engine, function, sentinel-1

I need help solving this GEE internal error. I am trying to reduce my script lines in GEE. So, I tried to use a single function to compute polarization indexes.

However, the console shows a warning saying: [image]

This is the script:

```
// Function to compute and add polarization indexes as bands
var addindexes = function(ima) {
  var NDPI = ima.select('VV').subtract(ima.select('VH'))
    .divide(ima.select('VV').add(ima.select('VH')));
  var NVHI = ima.select('VH').divide(ima.select('VV').add(ima.select('VH')));
  var NVVI = ima.select('VV').divide(ima.select('VV').add(ima.select('VH')));
  var VHrVV = ima.select('VH').divide(ima.select('VV'));
  var indexes = ee.List([NDPI,NVHI,NVVI,VHrVV]);
  return ima.addBands(indexes);
};

// Add index bands to image collection
var S1_indexes = allSeasons.map(addindexes);
print(S1_indexes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a full script it is a little difficult to debug, but one problem I see is that you are providing an `ee.List` object to the `addBands` method, but it requires an `ee.Image` object. Try using `ee.Image.cat` instead of `ee.List` like this:

```
// Make toy data
var allSeasons = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.Image.constant([25, 10]).rename('VV', 'VH'));
print(allSeasons);

// Function to compute and add polarization indexes as bands
var addindexes = function(ima) {
  var VV = ima.select('VV');
  var VH = ima.select('VH');
  var NDPI = VV.subtract(VH).divide(VV.add(VH));
  var NVHI = VH.divide(VV.add(VH));
  var NVVI = VV.divide(VV.add(VH));
  var VHrVV = VH.divide(VV);
  var indexes = ee.Image.cat(NDPI, NVHI, NVVI, VHrVV)
    .rename(['NDPI', 'NVHI', 'NVVI', 'VHrVV']);
  return ima.addBands(indexes);
};

// Add index bands to image collection
var S1_indexes = allSeasons.map(addindexes);
print(S1_indexes);
```

Note that I added two variables (VV and VH) so that `ima.select()` was not repeated.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked and It's even better than I expected.